# Iframe not loading the css from link tag under same domain in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm dynamically adding a `iframe` to html document using `javascript`.

```js
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#section-to-print').innerHTML;
```

When I add `css` using `link` tag from `same domain` to `iframe` head, the styles are not loading.

```js
let link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = "https://localhost:5001/css/invoice-receipt.css";      /**** your CSS file ****/
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.type = "text/css";
iframe.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(link);
```

But when I add the `css` using `style` tag it works.

```js
var styles = document.createElement("style");
styles.innerHTML = `html, body {
                width: 2.7in;
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: max-content;
            }`;
iframe.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(styles);
```

The problem is that I want to load different stylesheet dynamically but loading via link is not working. Please assist on what I'm missing.

Comment: You can only do that if you have the access to the source code for the iframe. For past 2 months I have worked over countless iframes but this is the problem that irritates the most. Either you get access to the source code or you just can't do it. The only way I guess is by making a request from the iframe to the page where you want to load it. Even for that you will need the access to the iframe code.

Comment: Also if you have access to the content of the iframe then try to take a look at these. It will surely work out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage && https://www.seancdavis.com/blog/manipulate-iframe-content/

Comment: I made it to work using scripts and posted this as an answer. Does this help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this to work using the below `script`.

```js
var bodyScript = document.createElement("script");
    bodyScript.innerHTML = `fetch('https://localhost:5001/css/invoice-receipt.css')
                            .then(response => response.text())
                            .then(data => {
                                var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                                    style = document.createElement('style');
                                head.appendChild(style);
                                style.type = 'text/css';
                                style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
                            });`;
    iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(bodyScript);
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was talking about sending a request